# What does this sentence of Greek means in the book of Modern Fourier Analysis?

Tags: soft-question, fourier-analysis

I am reading Loukas Grafakos' book *Modern Fourier Analysis* and found this apparently Greek text in the first pages

[image]

**What does it mean?**

Comment: I don't know Greek but I bet this is a dedication.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect something a little deeper involving Iona, Constantine and Theodora :-). Not exactly mathematics...

Comment: "For John, Constantin and Theodore"...or their female counterparts (Google translate. I only know the letters...:) )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means: "For (*or* dedicated to) Ioanna, Constantina and Theodora".

Comment: I suspect the Loukas in the OPs question would be the L. here...

Comment: If you read the OP's remarks carefully, you will see that the answer to your question is "yes"!  Happy Holidays!

Comment: The book is dedicated to his three daughters. A major revision of his two books are in preparation.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Do you know when they are coming out?

Comment: I suspect early 2014. He is finishing revision now, while on sabbatical.